# SAS - grouping and ordering of events by date

Tags: sas

This should be rather straightforward to do through SAS, I hope.
I want to know the order that person tried different drug therapies. Some people may try a therapy for more than 1 month, but really we just want to know what did they try first, what did they try second, and what did they try third. Some people will go back and forth on therapies, and this needs to be captured (person 1) for example:

`Unit       Item        Date Started

Person1     Yoga            1/1/2013
Person1     Vitamins        2/1/2013
Person1     Presciption     3/1/2013
Person1     Vitamins        4/1/2013
Person2     Vitamins        5/1/2012
Person2     Presciption     9/1/2013
Person2     Presciption     10/1/2013
Person3     Yoga            1/1/2013
Person3     Presciption     2/1/2013`

How can I summarize this in SAS into:

`Unit       Therapy1    Therapy2     Therapy 3      Therapy 4
Person 1    Yoga        Vitamins     Prescription   Vitamins
Person 2    Vitamins    Prescription
Person 3    Yoga        Prescription`

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: The question is ho to do this in SAS. I edited the post. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Create a flag indicating which therapy this is:

```
data want;
 set have;
 by unit item notsorted;  *notsorted means it looks at the data how it is and does not error for unordered by groups;
 if first.unit then therapy=0;   *start with 0 for each person.
 if first.item then thearapy+1;  *each time a different item comes in, increment therapy;
run;
```

Sort with `nodupkey` by `unit therapy`, then this is a textbook application of `proc transpose`.